# Best way to focus on my task without getting distracted

Tags: personal-care

I am programmer and have ADS so my problem in the most parts of my life  is concentrating because it's one of the important things I need. When I am programming, talking, making music, etc.

In the past I took medicine but didn't feel so good so I started to train my brain to concentrate better and longer.

I get distracted while I am doing my stuff and I am forced to isolate myself to a place where nobody is, but then I got distracted by the wall.

What are good tips to make it easier?

Comment: This looks like a psychological question, maybe it is not a good question for this site

Comment: nope it doesnt have any relation to psychologic because to get distracted is not an uncommon thing in our daily life and its not the problem that i cant concentrate .. its the problem that i cant do it within hours

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is asking for a mind hack, which is off-topic here. I'm am closing this question.

Comment: that is what I wanted to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m guessing that by ‘ads’ you mean some sort of attention deficit and/or hyperactivity disorder?

Could you talk to your boss about maybe taking several short breaks throughout the day rather than a single, long break?  You could use those short breaks to deal with distractions such as chatting to people, also maybe take a bit of exercise, then you may find yourself better able to concentrate while you are working.

Also, if possible, arrange your work so that you have more than one task on the go at a time.  That way you can switch back and forth between them rather than trying to focus all day on a single task and getting mentally fatigued.

Comment: wonderful and so helpful thank you perfect soloution !!! 
i just have short brakes to use my energy and yes  hyperactivitie too 
maybe i just start to do hard things like programming very hard structures to train my brain and burn my energy.. so also thank you :)